# React.js not accurate with setState

Tags: reactjs

Everytime I reload the page, I see some components that I hide using `{this.state.loggedIn? <Comp /> : null }` for few miliseconds. It's probably a big issue since the goal of setState is to respond and render correctly the views.

I start wondering it has something to do with firebase api, this is the function I'm running and on every reload I see the login form that I tried to hide using the method that I mentionned

```
componentDidMount = () => {
    fire.auth().onAuthStateChanged(user => {
        if (user) {
            this.setState({ loading: false, loggedIn: true });
        } else {
            this.setState({ loading: false, loggedIn: false });
        }
    });
};
```

In the constructor I initialize `loading:true` I don't see what I can do more to resolve that. Please someone assist

Comment: are you checking both of the fields in the `render` ?

Comment: You should check loading is equal to true in render method, if it is true, you should render loader only. It's better to see code in render method also

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First check if the app is loaded, then check if the user is logged in.

Something like this:

```
render() {
  <React.Fragment>
  {!this.state.loading ? (this.state.loggedIn ? <Comp /> : null) : null}
  </React.Fragment> 
}
```

or event cleaner:

```
{!this.state.loading && this.state.loggedIn && <Comp />}
```

Otherwise, here is a working example of the situation you describe:

```
import firebase from "firebase/app";
import "firebase/auth";

class App extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            loaded: false,
            auth: false
        };
    }

    componentWillMount = () => {
        const config = {
            //....
        };
        firebase.initializeApp(config);
        firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged(user => {
            if (user) {
                this.setState({ auth: true, loaded: true });
            } else {
                this.setState({ auth: false, loaded: true });
            }
        });
    };
    render() {
        return (
            <React.Fragment>
                {this.state.loaded ? (
                    !this.state.auth ? (
                        <LoginSplash />
                    ) : (
                        <MiniDrawer />
                    )
                ) : (
                    <div style={styles.Loading}>
                        <CircularProgress />
                        {"  Loading..."}
                    </div>
                )}
            </React.Fragment>
        );
    }
}

export default App;
```

Few things to check:

1. You imports: `import "firebase/auth";` &  `import firebase from "firebase/app";`
2. Your config is copied from firebase and you called `import firebase from "firebase/app";`
3. Check if the loaded is changed before checking for authentication

Comment: It will take a little bit of time to implement but I already like that architecture. Thanks for taking the time